# Why is Scrapy xpath selector not working?

Tags: scrapy, selector

I'm trying to extract the text from this Xpath in scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.matterhorngotthardbahn.ch/de/stories/autoverlad-furka'

response.xpath('//*[@id="prita-medium-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').getall()
```

it is the div class="rss-feed-description" content. However, it doesn't seem to work? anyone any idea why?

Comment: Attach the HTML element that you are wanting to get

Comment: because the page is loaded dynamically so the element you are looking for doesn't exist yet in the html

Comment: ok, meaning there is no way to extract data with scrapy? any other iedea to do that?

Comment: You can use Scrapy-playwright for dynamically loading pages. @Olivarsson